# What's more virtuous, to pray sitting or standing?

Tags: salat, nafl

Which is better, to spend Qiyam Al-Layl praying sitting, with khushoo and overall feeling comfortable, or to pray standing, tolerating pain because you've standing for some hours, with less or slightly less khushoo than sitting?

Comment: Questions asking about "better/worse, more/less" are often subjective and therefore hardly on-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Narrated by Ayesha(Ra.),“Do not ever stop praying Qiyaam. The Prophet  sallallaahu  `alayhi  wa  sallam ( may  Allah exalt his mention ) never ceased praying it. When he  sallallaahu`alayhi  wa  sallam ( may  Allah exalt his mention ) was sick or weak, he prayed sitting.” [Al-Bukhari and Muslim]

Answer (score 0):

Pray standing as much you can comfortably and then pray sitting is better if tired and can't focus.